# How do I find the last occurrence of a substring in an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, string

How would I get the last occurrence of an NSString within another NSString? For example, in "abc def ghi abc def ghi," I want to find the index of the second "abc," not the first. I know I could do this with a bunch of rangeOfStrings, but is there already a function for that?

Answer (score 287, accepted):

Use [`rangeOfString:options:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString:options:), including `NSBackwardsSearch` in the options.

```
[@"abc def ghi abc def ghi" rangeOfString:@"abc" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
```